# How to install from an url with hombrew?

Tags: homebrew, python, path

I would like to install a specific version of python3 (python 3.6.8) on my macbook.

I tried to:

```
brew install https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/python-3.6.6-macosx10.9.pkg
```

However, it doesnt work. What other options do I have for installing that specific version of python in my mac?

Comment: That file is already a macOS Installer Package. Which means if your just download it and double-click it... it will install. From the ReadMe.rtf file in that installer package it states: Python 3 and Python 2 Co-existence ... Python.org Python 3.6 and 2.7.x versions can both be installed on your system and will not conflict. Command names for Python 3 contain a 3 in them, python3 (or python3.6), idle3 (or idle3.6), pip3 (or pip3.6), etc.  Python 2.7 command names contain a 2 or no digit: python2 (or python2.7 or python), idle2 (or idle2.7 or idle), etc.

Comment: See [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)